# How to access Elasticache and Internet in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

I just wrote a python script that connect to the AWS ElastiCache. And it just check the connection.

```
from redis import Redis

try:
    redis = Redis(host='xxx.cache.amazonaws.com',
                  port=6379,
                  db=0)

    if not redis.ping():
        raise("REDIS can't be initialized")

    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    return False
```

When the following code is ran under my EC2 it has no problem and the response is reeally fast. Then I wrapped this using AWS Lambda and invoke the function locally. The returned result is still normal. But when the AWS Lambda is deployed on cloud the function got stuck on the `redis.ping()` until the function went timeout after 30 seconds.

I am not sure why the behavior is totally different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely due to networking, is your Lambda in a VPC, should it be, what does the routing look like?

Comment: Hmm I didn't configure the networking configuration. I just created the Redis partition and created the security group so the Redis port is enabled. I am now reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-elasticache-tutorial.html and config the network properties. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, follow [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: That video does not exist :'(

Comment: @JorgeOlaf I updated the answer and I guess the Amazon removed the video and updated their own answer.